# Jquery dialog modal not closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a dialog modal that is not closing when "save" or "cancel" are clicked.  I have compared to [jQuery UI's official demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and can't seem to find why this would not be working.

Here is what I have:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#DetailsWindow").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                title: 'Appointment Details',
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('button').click(function () {
                $("#DetailsWindow").dialog("open");
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
 <button>A button</button>
        <div id="DetailsWindow">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <span>Some Text</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `$('button')` query should be more restrictive, otherwise it matches ALL `<button>` tags on the page, including those inside the jQuery dialog, causing it to keep opening.

I would suggest adding a class to your main button:

```
<button class="open-details">A button</button>
```

And then change your JavaScript to:

```
$('button.open-details').click(function() {
    $("#DetailsWindow").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: +1, this is the issue.  The dialog is being closed, then immediately re-opened, because your handler is ran for the 'save' and 'cancel' buttons on the dialog.

Comment: Quoting the comment from the (now removed) answer: Actually, it is what you think it is. Inside those functions, this is the DOM element that you called .dialog on. From the docs (under 'Options' > 'buttons (object)'): "The context of the callback is the dialog element"

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
```

Instead of:

```
 $(this).dialog("close");
```